# FullCalendar - Make date not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm working with fullcalendar and am wondering if there is a way to make certain dates unclickable. The function I have so far compares all "day squares" dates on the calendar to a maximum date I have defined earlier. If the date goes beyond the max date I add a class to grey them out. They are still clickable. Hiding them screws with the layout of the calendar and looks awful.

```
            // Grey out the dates that go beyond the maximum availability date 
            var maxParsed = Date.parse(maxDate.toString());
            $("td[data-date]").each(function(){
                var date = $(this).data('date');
                var dateParsed = Date.parse(date);
                if(!isNaN(dateParsed) && dateParsed > maxParsed){
                    $(this).addClass('fc-other-month');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

With css only you can handle that, I think. On your css do this:

```
.fc-other-month {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

> The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what
>   circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the
>   target of mouse events. When this property is unspecified, the same
>   characteristics of the visiblePainted value apply to SVG content.

You can know more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

If it doesn't work, maybe a prevent default can do the trick.

```
$('.fc-other-month').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).css({'pointer-events' : 'none'});
});
```

=== edit ====

I looked into documentation, they have `eventClick`. You can inside that function check if it's a "good date" or not and then return false if you don't want to be clickable.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        if ( 1==1 || "this is a day without click feature") { //dummy code
           return false; //prevent clickable function
        }

    }
});
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/

Comment: These did not work. I even tried removing all the classes from the day square (as far as I can tell they just controlled color/position etc.) and calling .unbind() to unbind all events. Still clickable..

Comment: Are you sure? I added directly on the demo (devtools) `pointer-events: none` and the numbers stopped being clickable. I also forced with js to add that css. try it again

Answer (score 0):

Take help of jQuery and `return false` on `click` event (I guess you assigned it different class) on the date you do not wish to be clicked. So they do not act on click...